# Justify-content:space-between not working

Tags: html, css

Just to create a modal widow with two bottoms at the boom (download and close) Hoping to use `justify-content:space-between`. Is this due to the items not being buttons? Going to make them clickable later.

The modal window will eventually contain an image carousel in the red area with general text in the green.

Any help is appreciated.

Here is a photo of my current result:
[image]

```css
// Modal Pop-up cotainer
.bg-modal {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.modal-container {
  width: 700px;
  height: 800px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.autoFP-image-carousel {
  position: relative;
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65%;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}

.autoFP-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: green;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40%;
}

.visit-close-bttn {
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-around;
}
```

```html
<div class="bg-modal">
  <div class="modal-container">
    <div class="autoFP-image-carousel">

    </div>
    <div class="autoFP-content">
      <h2>Flight Plan Automation</h2>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
      <div class="visit-close-bttn">
        <div>check</div>
        <div class="close">+</div>
      </div>
      <!-- Exit btn -->

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but not working?

Answer (score 0):

Realized I did not set the width of the div to its parent container.